# Indirectly referenced from required .class file, even the build path is set correctly apache POI..?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, apache-poi, buildpath

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.*;
import org.apache.poi.hpsf.DocumentSummaryInformation;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.HeaderStories;

public class ReadDocFileInJava {

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      /**This is the document that you want to read using Java.**/
      String fileName = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\kushalp\\Desktop\\Test.doc";

      /**Method call to read the document (demonstrate some useage of POI)**/
      readMyDocument(fileName);
   }
   public static void readMyDocument(String fileName)
   {
         POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
         try 
         {
             fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(fileName));
             HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);

             /** Read the content **/
             readParagraphs(doc);

             int pageNumber=1;

             /** We will try reading the header for page 1**/
             readHeader(doc, pageNumber);

             /** Let's try reading the footer for page 1**/
             readFooter(doc, pageNumber);

             /** Read the document summary**/
             readDocumentSummary(doc);

         } 
         catch (Exception e) 
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
   }  

   public static void readParagraphs(HWPFDocument doc) throws Exception
   {
       WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);

       /**Get the total number of paragraphs**/
       String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
       System.out.println("Total Paragraphs: "+paragraphs.length);

       for (int i = 0; i &lt; paragraphs.length; i++) 
       {

            System.out.println("Length of paragraph "+(i +1)+": "+ paragraphs[i].length());
            System.out.println(paragraphs[i].toString());
       }
   }

   public static void readHeader(HWPFDocument doc, int pageNumber)
   {
       HeaderStories headerStore = new HeaderStories( doc);
       String header = headerStore.getHeader(pageNumber);
       System.out.println("Header Is: "+header);
   }

   public static void readFooter(HWPFDocument doc, int pageNumber)
   {
       HeaderStories headerStore = new HeaderStories( doc);
       String footer = headerStore.getFooter(pageNumber);
       System.out.println("Footer Is: "+footer);
   }

   public static void readDocumentSummary(HWPFDocument doc) 
   {
       DocumentSummaryInformation summaryInfo=doc.getDocumentSummaryInformation();
       String category = summaryInfo.getCategory();
       String company = summaryInfo.getCompany();
       int lineCount=summaryInfo.getLineCount();
       int sectionCount=summaryInfo.getSectionCount();
       int slideCount=summaryInfo.getSlideCount();

       System.out.println("---------------------------");
       System.out.println("Category: "+category);
       System.out.println("Company: "+company);
       System.out.println("Line Count: "+lineCount);
       System.out.println("Section Count: "+sectionCount);
       System.out.println("Slide Count: "+slideCount);

   }
```

I am getting error in these two packages

import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.*;

import org.apache.poi.hpsf.DocumentSummaryInformation;

The type org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I have attached a snapshot my java build path...since the program require

poi-scratchpad-3.2-FINAL-20081019.jar

It is correctly set in java build path..then why I am getting such error ..help..!![image]

[image]

Comment: so does the jar actually contain `org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem`  see http://www.findjar.com/class/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem.html

Answer (score 5):

found the solution it requires poi-3.7.jar

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/3.7

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems. One is that you're using Apache POI 3.2, which dates from [6 years ago](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.2-FINAL) and there have been a [huge number of bug fixes since then](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.2-FINAL)

Second problem, you've missed [some of the POI jars and their dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components). See the [components page for details](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components). Basically though, to use HWPF, you need *both* the `poi` *and* `poi-scratchpad` jars on your classpath

Answer (score 0):

delete entire released directories located at `C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi`.

Right Click on `project > Maven` then `Update project`.